function of random variables - change of variables
Consider two independent random variables $X \sim p_X$, $Y \sim p_Y$. Let $Z$ be a deterministic function of $X,Y$, $z = g(x,y)$, with distribution $Z \sim p_Z$.
Does the following identity hold for a function $f$?
$$
\int f(z) \, d p_Z(z) = \iint f(g(x,y)) \, d p_X(x) \, d p_Y(y)
$$

Of course yes..

@Will Yeah, it seems too obvious that this holds. But, is there any specific argument to justify it?

$$
\begin{align}
\int f(z)p_Z(z)\,dz&=\mathbb E[f(Z)]\\
&=\mathbb E[f(g(X,Y))]\\
&=\int f(g(x,y))p_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy\\
&=\int\int f(g(x,y))p_X(x)p_Y(y)\,dx\,dy,
\end{align}$$
where I used of course that the density $p_{X,Y}$ of $(X,Y)$ is the product density of $p_X$ by $p_Y$ as $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
